# Unable to debug web control click handler

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-debugging, web-controls

ASP.NET WebForms application.  There is a custom web control (IE inherits from System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl).  I can put breakpoints anywhere in CreateChildControls() or any other overloaded method and these breakpoints work fine.  However, if I try to add a breakpoint to a method that is bound to a Button on the page, I get an error on the breakpoint:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No executable code of the debugger's target code is associated with this line.  Possible causes include: conditional compilation, compiler optimizations, or the target architecture of this line is not supported by the current debugger code type.
```

I've tried cleaning the solution, deleting all bin/obj folders, restarting local IIS, recycling the app pool, all to no avail.

Code is in VB.NET (sorry).
Here is the function definition (in the WebControl code):

```
 Private Sub AddToCartClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
      // breakpoint on line 1
```

Here is the code that ties the function to the Button:

```
 Dim button = new Button
 AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf AddToCartClick
```

The code executes and has worked for a long time, but I cannot debug it with breakpoints.

Comment: I think the error message is (for once) pretty clear. Are you in debug mode?  Have you unchecked enable optimizations in the project settings? The compiler will inline all kinds of things with this setting checked which is why the code cannot  be reached.

Comment: I am in debug mode, optimizations are unchecked.. to no avail.  This is the same code-behind where I can reach with the debugger for ASP defined overrides, but cannot get to a breakpoint in a bound Click handler (though the code does execute).